# using the verb "to be" with the word "above"

Tags: prepositional-verbs

Are these correct?

> Health is above wealth.
>   No one is above the law.
>   The old man is above ninety.
>   I am above forty.

if it's OK, can you please give me another example?

Comment: When speaking of people's ages, it's more usual to say 'over ninety'. "Above the law" is OK - it's an idiom meaning "too powerful to have to obey the law". A similar expression is "above suspicion", meaning "too well-respected to be readily suspected of wrong-doing". You can say that someone _values_ health above wealth, but with _is_ I would use 'more important than'.

Answer (score 1):

> Health is above wealth.
>       No one is above the law.

These are correct use.  "above" indicates the preceding concept or idea is more important than the following or in some way takes priority,

> The old man is above ninety.
>       I am above forty.

These are not strictly correct, but are intelligible - English speakers will understand you but you will sound awkward.

Better are "The old man is older than ninety" and "I am older than forty". You can also use "over":  "The old man is over ninety [years old]".

(Some people will say "better than" if they want to be careful about not invoking the stigma of age; you might see "for active adults better than 75 years of age" on a retirement home advertisement.)

Comment: Another (very common) example of "above" with "to be" is if you want to indicate physical position: "The sky is above the Earth".

Comment: thanks what is the opposite side of above,

Comment: He is under forty.

Comment: The opposite of "above" is "below", (but we don't use below to indicate importance: no one would say "wealth is below health".)

Comment: so, is it right to say: wealth is under health

Comment: No.  That sounds like it is literally underneath, in space.  Say the thing that is  better/more important first to use this idiom.  Likewise, you could also say "health before wealth" and that conveys the same meaning, but "wealth after health" does not have that meaning - it sounds like if you have health, then you will definitely have wealth later.